14.2 Final Project: Fibonacci sequence Zybooks Labs
`It says that my score was a 13/25, so I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
The Fibonacci sequence begins with 0 and then 1 follows. All subsequent values are the sum of the previous two, ex: 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13. Complete the fibonacci() function, which has an index, n (starting at 0), as a parameter and returns the nth value in the sequence. Any negative index values should return -1.
Ex: If the input is:
7
the output is:
fibonacci(7) is 13
Here is my code:
`def fibonacci(n):`
`a = 0`
`b = 1`
`c = 1                       # Define the result variable here`

    if (n < 0):                 # Specifically return -1 for any entry of a negative number
        return -1
    
    print("0  ", end="")        # Starting number is "0"
    
    for i in range(1,n):
        print(c, " ", end="")   # Start printing Fibonacci values beginning with "0 + 1"
        c = a + b
        a = b
        b = c
    
    print(c, " ")               # Print final value 
    return c

`if `__`name`__` == '`__`main`__`':`
`start_num = int(input("Enter a number: "))`
`` print(f'fibonacci({start_num}) is {fibonacci(start_num)}')` ``


fibonacci(0) should return 0. As written, it returns 1.

That's not working for some reason

Is your fibonacci(0) returning 1 an expected (to you!) behavior? If no, you should figure how to debug your program and the question is about recommending debugging instruments for your environment. If yes, why didn't you see this wrong behavior before? Do you have trouble coming up with tests of your own? With running said tests? With fixing the program, even if you understand how it produces the wrong result and what would be the right one?

Can you show me how my code is supposed to look like?
